# Differences between “Oui” and “Si” in the affirmative?

Tags: choix-de-mot, négation, questions

The usual form of yes in French is "oui."

But my understanding is that there is another form of the affirmative, "si," (similar to the Spanish). It is used only in limited contexts, and is perhaps a different, "weaker" way of saying "yes."

In Japanese, for example, there is a word "hai," which is a "conditional" yes.

In what contexts are "si" used, and how does it differ from "oui"?

Comment: Small aside: I would *strongly* question your two claims above regarding the origin of "si", which comes from Latin, not Spanish, afaik, and "hai" (はい) which is most most likely a native Japanese word, not Chinese (and *can* be used to answer by the affirmative to a question, btw).

Comment: @Dave: I have shortened the Japanese reference, and altered the Spanish reference.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

"si" is only used to answer a negative question or assertion and contradict it: ([*Contredit un énoncé négatif*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/si) - see the third tab [SI<sup>3</sup>, adv.])

> *Tu ne manges pas?* (Are you not eating?)
>   *Si, j'arrive.* (On the contrary, I'll be right there)

Contrast with the negative answer:

> *Non, je n'ai pas faim.* (No, I'm not hungry)

Another example, not on a question.

> *Tu ne fais jamais la vaisselle!* (You never do the dishes!)
>   *Si, je l'ai faite hier.* (On the contrary, I did them yesterday)

vs.

> *Non, et alors.* (Indeed I don't, so what?)

"oui" is used to answer a positive question:

> *Tu veux du pain?* (Do you want some bread?)
>   *Oui, merci.* (Yes, thanks.)

vs.

> *Non, merci.* (No thanks.)

Also, note that *en effet* can be used to agree with the other person, regardless of whether he used a positive or negative sentence/question:

> *En effet, je n'ai pas faim.* (Indeed, I'm not hungry)
>   *En effet, je ne fais jamais la vaisselle.* (Indeed, I never do the dishes.)
>   *En effet, je veux du pain.* (Indeed, I want bread — although that one is weird, unless you got some golden tattoo on your forehead.)

Comment: Pour être complet, ça vaut peut-être la peine de mentionner comment formuler l'« autre » réponse dans chacun des exemples. « Non, je n'ai pas faim… »

Comment: C'est pas faux...

Comment: Peut-être une erreur mais je peux sans problème mettre *Oui* à la place de *Si* dans tous les exemples sans me sentir coupable... Doit-on donc dire que l'on peut mettre *Oui* dans tous les cas et *Si* parfois (comme tu l'as bien expliqué), ou est-ce que dans certains cas *Si* est correct alors que *Oui* ne l'est pas ?

Comment: LudoMC - Examine ceci: "Tu ne fais jamais la vaisselle!" "Oui, je l'ai faite hier". Cela ne marche pas en Francais. "Oui" indique seulement qu'on est d'accord. "Si" indique une reponse contraire et positive.

Comment: @LudoMC : Au Québec (et peut-être dans d'autres pays francophones, je ne sais pas) on remplacera sans problème "si" par "oui" dans chacune des phrases citées. En France, par contre, "oui" serait incompréhensible.

Comment: @Brennan Vincent J'ai du passer un peu trop de temps au Québec alors :) Et puis de toute façon, je fais la vaisselle, donc cette question ne me concerne pas ;)

Comment: « Oui, merci » n'est pas idiomatique, je mettrais plutôt « Oui, s'il te plait ».

Comment: @Trevoke si le mot "oui" indique qu'on est d'accord, alors comment repondrait-on a la question "C'est impossible?" Dirait-on "Si, c'est possible", "Non, c'est possible" ou "Oui, c'est possible"?

Comment: @soktinpk Strictement parlant, la reponse serait "Non, ce n'est pas impossible". En pratique, on dirait "Non, c'est possible". Si la question etait "Ce n'est pas possible?", alors la reponse serait "Si, c'est possible".

Answer (score 27):

OK, this is more like a long comment, because the answer has already been given with lots of details by Joubarc and others. Yet, I feel like these answers could be expanded a bit in terms of generality, so here I go… I’ll do so in French, and refer you to a [related answer on English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28581/did-english-ever-have-a-word-for-yes-for-negative-questions) for an English reply (by yours truly).

---

Pour ce qui est des réponses aux questions fermées (questions « oui ou non »), on peut classer les différents languages en fonction du nombre de réponses possibles, qui peut aller jusqu'à quatre :

> - Viendras-tu ? AAA, je viendrai.
> - Viendras-tu ? BBB, je ne viendrai pas.
> - Ne viendras-tu pas ? CCC, je viendrai.
> - Ne viendras-tu pas ? DDD, je ne viendrai pas.

La plupart des langues peuvent se classer selon le nombre de réponses possibles :

- Les systèmes à deux formes : par exemple, l'anglais moderne n'a que *yes* et *no*. On a donc :

  > AAA = CCC = yes  (« yes, I will come » que la question soit positive ou négative)
  >   BBB = DDD = no (« no, I won't come » dans les deux cas)

  Se classent parmi les langues à deux formes : l'anglais (*yes/no*), l'espagnol (*si/no*), l'italien (*si/no*), le portugais (*sim/não*) et le grec (*ναι/όχι*).
- Les systèmes à quatre formes : de manière surprenant, c'était le cas de l'anglais [jusqu'à l'époque élisabethaine](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28581) (*Early Modern English*) :

  > ◊ Will he go? — **Yea**, he will.
  >   ◊ Will he go? — **Nay**, he will not.
  >   ◊ Will he not go? — **Yes**, he will.
  >   ◊ Will he not go? — **No**, he will not.

  Les quatres réponses sont différentes, *yes/no/yea/nay*. Le seul autre exemple que j'ai trouvé est le roumain (*da/nu/ba da/ba nu*).
- Les systèmes à trois formes, dont le français (*oui/non/si*), le danois et le suédois (*ja/nej/jo*), le norvégien (*ja/nei/jo*), l'islandais (*ja/jú/nei*), le hongrois (*igen/nem/de*) et l'allemand (*ja/nein/doch*). Ils fonctionnent tous selon le même mode, c'est-à-dire BBB = DDD ; autrement dit, ce sont les deux réponses affirmatives qui sont différenciées:

  > ◊ Viendras-tu ? — **Oui**, je viendrai.
  >   ◊ Viendras-tu ? — **Non**, je ne viendrai pas.
  >   ◊ Ne viendras-tu pas ? — **Si**, je viendrai.
  >   ◊ Ne viendras-tu pas ? — **Non**, je ne viendrai pas.

En plus de tout cela, certaines langues n'ont pas de mots pour *oui* et *non*, et réutilisent le verbe de la question (telles que le Latin). Enfin, des langues comme le japonais fonctionnent sur un système d'accord avec la proposition énoncée (voir pour les détails le [lien](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/the-reality-of-answering-to-a-negative-question) de Dave).

Références : [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_and_no#The_English_four-form_and_two-form_systems), [ce site](http://aveneca.com/yesno.html) pour les listes de langues par système.

Comment: Très intéressant, would upvote again!

Comment: Et avec tout ça, finalement, on ne sait toujours pas si tu viendras.

Comment: Alors ça c'est intéressant. Je me suis toujours demandé, quand quelqu'un disait *"Tu n'es pas d'accord ?"* et qu'on répondait *"oui"*, si ça voulait dire qu'on est d'accord ou bien qu'on n'est effectivement pas d'accord. La réponse est donc qu'il est impossible de répondre *"oui"* et il y a même une règle avec les formes.

Comment: Si je me souviens bien, le breton a aussi quatre formes.

Answer (score 11):

Il s'agit de la négation d'une négation.

> — Tu comprends ?
>
> — Oui.

Means "yes, I understand."

> — Tu ne comprends pas ?
>
> — Si

Means "no, I don't *not understand*"… Hence, "I *do* understand" :-)

Saying « oui » in that context, is ambivalent and could be understood as « oui, je ne comprends pas. » Although the correct form would be « non, je ne comprends pas. »

Answer (score 9):

Actually Japanese is an interesting example, because it is a language that uses "yes" and "no" the opposite way of English when replying to a negative question.

> -- *Aren't you coming?*
>
> -- *No.*

In English, *"no"* means here *"no, I am not"*. In Japanese it would mean *"your affirmation is false, I am"*.

French works the same way as English and Spanish here: replying *"no"* to a negative sentence is agreeing. In the case of *"yes"*, the word is not *"oui"* anymore, but *"si"*.

In a sense *"si"* is stronger than *"oui"*, since *"oui"* means you agree, while *"si"* means you do not agree, quite the opposite!

Comment: There is indeed a fundamental difference in how Japanese and most European languages work for yes/no questions, but it's [a little more complicated than that](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/the-reality-of-answering-to-a-negative-question).

Comment: Oh yes it is, and I am not even sure I have it correctly yet. :) This was just meant to be quick example since Tom mentioned Japanese. Thank you for the link! On a side note, I think Filipino too works this way; I don't know yet which families of languages do.