# Comment exprimer son agrément avec une négation : par « oui » ou par « non » ?

Tags: négation

Exemple :

> — Ce n'est pas une question déjà posée.
>
> — Non, c'en est une nouvelle.

ou

> — Ce n'est pas une question déjà posée.
>
> — Oui, c'en est une nouvelle.

Comment: related http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/848/differences-between-oui-and-si-in-the-affirmative/864#864

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'agrément s'exprime normalement avec un « non » qui reprend la négation de l'assertion.

> — Ce n'est pas une question déjà posée.
>
> — Non, c'en est une nouvelle.

*Oui* est peu idiomatique ici mais néanmoins équivalent à *non*.

> — Oui, c'en est une nouvelle.

Référence: TLFi, « [*oui*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/oui) »

```
Oui, adv.
...
III. − [En concurrence avec non; marque l'acceptation d'un énoncé négatif: là
où non porterait sur l'énoncé lui-même (en confirmant son signe négatif), oui
porte sur l'énonciation et signifie «vous avez raison de dire que (+ énoncé
négatif)», «il est vrai que (+ énoncé négatif)»]
```

On pourrait donc aussi répondre,

> — C'est vrai, c'en est une nouvelle.

La contradiction utilise *si*:

> — Si, c'est une question déjà posée !

Référence: TLFi, « [*non*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/non) »

```
Non, adv.
...
B. − [Signifie l'acceptation d'un énoncé négatif; s'oppose à si exprimant le
rejet]
```

Comment: Whoa, I've never seen the contract *c'en* before. I mean I understand perfectly, just haven't seen it before.

Comment: @jlliagre "Ce n'est pas une question déjà posée" n'est pas une question mais une assertion. Peut-être aurais-je dû dire:

Comment: D'accord. Ça ne change pas fondamentalement ma réponse que je met quand même à jour.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est bien ce que je pensais mais je voudrais convaincre quelqu'un. Pourriez-vous me donner une référence?

Comment: @Aerovistae E.g. C'en est fait de moi.

Comment: Référence ajoutée

Comment: I agree with the good analyse by jiliagre, except for the fact of accepting the answer "oui, c'en est une nouvelle", which is nonsense. The fact that some people, maybe, would use "oui" instead of "non" doesn't have to let us accept it as a French form. A mistake remains a mistake. The only case where we can accept a mistake is when it contains a new idea, or a new meaning or at least a touch of humour.

Comment: Répondre "oui" à une question négative supprime l'ambigüité qu'on a avec "non", car parfois le fait que la question soit négative ou non est difficile à cerner. Par exemple, si on te dit "Tu n'as pas l'air en forme aujourd'hui" et que tu réponds "non", ce n'est pas évident de savoir ce que tu entends par là, alors qu'avec "oui" c'est clair: tu est d'accord avec l'assertion.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci pour la référence. D'autant plus que je ne connaissais pas TLFi.

Comment: @BBBreiz Using *oui* instead of *non* is neither a mistake nor a nonsense. Answer updated with references.

Comment: à Anne Aunyme : Votre exemple est ambigü et aussi factice que celui de @jiliagre: son "Oui, c'en est une nouvelle" est vraiment irréel, c'est évident si l'on se représente la situation dialoguée. Et dans votre cas, on entendrait certainement pas un "oui" sec, mais plutôt "non, en effet".

Comment: ... alors qu'avec un "oui" sec toute l'information serait passée en une syllabe. Celui qui répond "non, en effet" a du temps à perdre, dans la pratique les gens (surtout ceux qui "n'ont pas l'air en forme" comme dans mon exemple) répondent par une seule syllabe quand ils le peuvent. De plus j'ai très souvent entendu répondre "non" sec à des questions du type "tu n'as pas oublié de faire XXX?", "Tu ne connaîtrais pas XXX?", et c'est très énervant car cette réponse est complètement non porteuse de sens.

Comment: @BBBreiz Il ne s'agit pas de **mon** « Oui, c'en est... » mais la reprise de la question posée. À une proposition négative, seule une réponse introduite par *si* n'est pas ambiguë. Les réponses en *oui* ou en *non* peuvent, l'une comme l'autre, parfois exprimer l'agrément ou la contradiction. Elles requièrent alors un complément précisant la pensée. c.f. non tlfi: *Rem. Dans les cas énumérés sous 2, oui serait également possible. Il porterait non pas sur le dit, mais sur le dire: Le divorce, ce n'est pas une chose pour votre famille −Oui, ne t'en fais pas («oui, tu as raison de dire que...»).*

Comment: à jiliagre et Anne Aunyme. Voici la définition du Grand Robert, édition 1984: "Oui. Adverbe équivalent à une proposition affirmative qui répond à une affirmation non accompagnée de négation". Je pense que cette explication doit vous suffire...

Comment: @BBBreiz Hmm, comment dire ... non ;-) Personne ne conteste que l'usage est nettement en faveur du non pour agréer une proposition négative, mais l'utilisation de oui ne viole aucune règle grammaticale, s'explique aisément, est documentée et se rencontre parfois dans la littérature comme dans la vie de tous les jours.

Comment: Pour ce qui est de cette question, nous nous quitterons donc sur un désaccord, car l'existence du mauvais usage ne justifie pas à mes yeux son agrément dans la théorie de la langue, sans quoi il faudrait se sentir obligé d'ajouter au dictionnaire des milliers de mots de "verlan" qui dénaturent notre langue et que nous n'avons pas à propager aux étrangers qui désirent l'apprendre. L'usage du "oui" que vous défendez existe peut-être à la marge, mais il est aussi mauvais que l'omission du subjonctif.

Comment: ...aussi mauvais que l'omission du subjonctif, en cela qu'il introduit une ambiguïté stérile qui nuit à l'efficacité du langage. Accorder le même sens à deux réponses contradictoires introduit dans la langue une confusion nocive, et c'est précisément pourquoi les fautes sont nuisibles et n'ont pas à être défendues;

Comment: « Non, c'en est une nouvelle » et « Oui, c'en est une nouvelle » ne sont pas des réponses contradictoires mais deux manières différentes d'exprimer une réponse identique. Seule une réponse sèche aurait éventuellement pu être ambiguë, mais faudrait-il aussi interdire l'usage des mots *hôte*, *louer* ou *plus* sous prétexte de leur potentialité amphibologique ?

Comment: @ Anne Aunyme et Aerovistae et guillaume girod-vitouchkina. Sans vouloir être désagréable, puis-je me permettre de vous faire remarquer que j'avais pris bien soin d'indiquer qu'il ne s'agissait pas d'une réponse à une _question_ mais de tout autre chose, à savoir d'un agrément avec une negation qui est une _assertion_?  Le problème avec ce genre d'inattention est que cela "noie le poisson".

Answer (score 2):

There's a handy word *si* just for this. It means *yes* to a negative question. So, behold:

> Are you coming?
>   Yes, I am. (*Oui.*)
>
> Are you not coming?
>   Yes, I am! (*Si!*)
>
> Are you coming?
>   No, I'm not. (*Non.*)
>
> Are you not coming?
>   No, I'm not. (*Non.*)

So if asked *Tu viens pas ?*, and you *are* coming, you can say *Si, je viens!*

Answer (score 1):

**Question avec forme positive => oui ou non**

Manges-tu des pommes ?

=> **oui** (j'en mange) / **non** (je n'en mange pas)

**Question avec forme négative => non ou si**

Ne prends-tu pas des gants ? Tu ne prends pas des gants ?

=> **non** (je ne prends pas de gantss ) ou **si** ( je prends des gants)