# « Je n'ai jamais été aussi < caractérisation > »: « moi aussi » ou « moi non plus » ?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, usage

Une personne dit : « Je n'ai jamais été aussi heureux !  »
Son ami, qui partage la même opinion, lui répond ; doit-il dire « Moi aussi » ou « Moi non plus » ?
Même question avec « malheureux » à la place de  « heureux ».

Comment: Pour le 3ème tag de la question, https://genius.com/Serge-gainsbourg-je-taime-moi-non-plus-lyrics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les deux réponses se disent et signifient toutes deux un acquiescement.

> **Moi aussi** (je partage ce sentiment).

> **Mon non plus** (je ne l'ai jamais été).

On peut contourner ce choix en répondant :

> C'est pareil pour moi
> Moi de même
> Moi, pareil
> Pareillement
> ...

Pour répondre négativement, on peut dire :

> **Moi, si**. (Je l'ai déjà été)

Que la phrase contienne heureux ou malheureux n'a pas d'influence.

Voir aussi cette question très similaire:
[Comment exprimer son agrément avec une négation : par « oui » ou par « non » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/18904/1109)

Answer (score 1):

Pour ce qui est des réactions suite à une phrase affirmative on utilise toujours « moi aussi » si on affirme qu'il en va de même pour soi-même. Lorsque la phrase est négative *et qu'il s'agit d'une négation simple (ne…pas)* c'est toujours  « moi non plus ». Ces faits de base se trouvent consignés dans cette page [Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-31470.php).

Il existe une difficulté lorsque la négation est complexe (ne ... rien, ne ... plus, ne ... jamais, ne ... personne, ne ... aucun) parce que la négation n'est pas ressentie pleinement, ce que confirme le langage parlé, dans le lequel est soustraite la particule négative.

- Il dit rien de la journée.//Vous travaillez plus, alors c'est normal.//Tu verras jamais la fin de cette route, elle fait un cercle.//…

Il est néanmoins correct de traiter les négations complexes comme les simples. Cette [page-ci](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22jamais+moi+non+plus%22&lr=lang_fr&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1fr,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_iN6CnvvuAhXT3YUKHevBDtsQpwUIJA&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1) ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jamais+moi+non+plus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjamais%20moi%20non%20plus%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cjamais%20moi%20non%20plus%3B%2Cc0)) montre de nombreux cas où « moi non plus » correspond à « ne … jamais », alors que le [tests « jamais moi aussi »](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jamais+moi+aussi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=) est complètement négatif ; il faut donc dire « moi non plus ».
(On a le même résultat pour « rien moi non plus » ([réf.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rien+moi+non+plus%22&lr=lang_fr&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1fr,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiolInoo_vuAhVSx4UKHbCtBBoQpwUIJA&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1), ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rien+moi+non+plus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crien%20moi%20non%20plus%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crien%20moi%20non%20plus%3B%2Cc0)), [rien moi aussi](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rien+moi+aussi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=)).)

Il reste maintenant ce cas spécial abordé dans les commentaires ("Je n'ai envie de manger que de la viande" ou "Je n'ai que toi". Doit-on répondre "Moi non plus" ou "Moi aussi" à ces phrases ?). Il n'y a aucun doute dans ce cas-là (il ne s'agit que d'un et du même principe dans les deux phrases.), seulement « moi aussi » convient. La raison de cela est que l'adverbe « ne » ne représente nullement la négation dans ce cas, où il entre en combinaison  avec « que » pour signifier « seulement » ([réf.](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2466)).

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse détaillée. Cependant, la recherche de n-gramme ne correspond pas exactement à la question puisqu'ici le « aussi » rajoute une complexité supplémentaire. Y a-t-il moyen de trouver les n-grammes sur cette construction particulière ?

Comment: @AntoineDusséaux Je ne vois pas ce que vous reprochez aux ngrams ; pourriez-vous montrer le défaut que vous semblez trouver ?

Comment: La structure de la phrase demandée est "jamais aussi xxx moi non plus" et non pas uniquement "jamais moi non plus". Vous voyez ce que je veux dire ?

Comment: @AntoineDusséaux Ah! oui, bien sûr, veuillez m'excuser, j'aurais dû faire plus attention. Non, je suis sûr qu'il n'y a  pas de différence. _ex._ : Je n'ai jamais été **plus/si/aussi** malade ; moi non plus.//Je n'ai jamais été malade **en bateau** ; moi non plus.//On peut varier la construction de base et ajouter des adverbes, cela n'a aucune incidence sur la construction. Il est seulement nécessaire que la négation soit une des soit disant négations complexes.

Answer (score 0):

La forme la plus correcte est de dire "moi non plus" (c'est le seul cas d'usage de cette expression : pour abonder dans le sens d'une expression négative).

Comment: Merci. Le problème ici c'est que la phrase est grammaticalement négative mais "positive" dans son sens ("Je suis très heureux") et donc la réponse "Moi non plus" est "étrange" je trouve et je me demandais s'il y avait des exceptions. Un cas similaire serait : "Je n'ai envie de manger que de la viande" ou "Je n'ai que toi". Doit-on répondre "Moi non plus" ou "Moi aussi" à ces phrases ?

Comment: @AntoineDusséaux : mais il n'y a aucune raison que nier une proposition soit quelque chose de négatif ! Associer la négation au mal est une drôle d'idée... Cependant, les cas avec ne... que... sont différents : il ne s'agit pas d'une négation ici mais d'une restriction, et il faut donc répondre "moi aussi". Vous pouvez comparer avec "Je n'ai pas que toi" et "Je n'ai pas envie de manger que de la viande" (auxquelles on répondra "moi non plus").