# « Si » ou « oui » pour contredire une question affirmative

Tags: choix-de-mot, négation, questions

J'ai déja vu cette question-ci : [Differences between “Oui” and “Si” in the affirmative?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/848/differences-between-oui-and-si-in-the-affirmative), mais il me reste une question. Si la question est négative, mais posée affirmativement, comment répondrait-on?

Par exemple, si on posait la question « C'est impossible ? » ou « Est-ce impossible ? » et que je voulais dire qu'en fait, c'est possible, est-ce que je dirais « Si, c'est possible, » « Non, c'est possible » ou « Oui, c'est possible » ? Et comment est-ce que je dirais que « c'est vrai, c'est impossible » : « Non, c'est impossible. » ou « Oui, c'est impossible » ?

Je sais que si on posait la question « Ce n'est pas possible ? » je pourrais dire « Si, c'est possible » ou « Non, ce n'est pas possible, » mais que dirait-on si une question négative est cachée dans une question affirmative ?

Comment: Pour les québécois: https://youtu.be/rBSflK1FTSY?t=78

Answer (score 5):

Bien que techniquement positive, la question « **C'est impossible ?** » peut être facilement assimilée à son équivalent négatif « **Ce n'est pas possible ?** »

En fonction de la question implicite que la réponse reprend et contredit ou approuve, on rencontrera donc les cas suivant:

---

— **Non, ce n'est pas impossible !** (Contredit « **C'est impossible ?** » )

— **Oui, c'est impossible !** (Approuve « **C'est impossible ?** » )

---

— **Si, c'est possible !** (Contredit « **Ce n'est pas possible ?** » )

— **Non, ce n'est pas possible !** (Approuve « **Ce n'est pas possible ?** » )

---

En revanche, la réponse suivante est plus rare car elle ne respecte pas la logique habituelle de la contradiction. Elle est cependant tout à fait acceptable car suffisamment explicite :

— **Non, c'est possible !** (Contredit « **Ce n'est pas possible ?** » )

On peut aussi rencontrer cette réponse, elle aussi rare, où « oui » est en concurrence avec « non » :

— **Oui, ce n'est pas possible !** (Approuve « **Ce n'est pas possible ?** » )

Voici un exemple de contradiction d'une question négative implicite trouvé dans la [plaidoirie](https://affairesetproces.blogspot.fr/2013_02_01_archive.html) d'un avocat:

> Me Edouard Martial, partie civile pour les membres de la famille Aïssa, a encore fait pleurer sur les bancs lorsqu'il évoqua «un garçon joyeux qui «ne parlera plus jamais». De même quand il lança : «Un homme qui en tue un autre et le met sur un bûcher, **c'est impossible ? Si, c'est possible…** Un homme qui en découpe un autre, **c'est impossible ? Si c'est possible…**».

Voir aussi [Comment exprimer son agrément avec une négation : par « oui » ou par « non » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18904/comment-exprimer-son-agr%C3%A9ment-avec-une-n%C3%A9gation-par-oui-ou-par-non/18908#18908)

Comment: Juste une remarque, « acquiescer » avec un C, est intransitif.

Comment: @toto C'est vrai, je me doutais bien que quelque chose clochait...

Answer (score 4):

La question est affirmative, il faut donc répondre par "Oui/Non".

> -C'est impossible ?
>   -Non, c'est tout à fait possible / Oui, c'est impossible

Il est aussi déconseillé de répondre simplement "oui", "non", ou "si" à ce genre de question, car cela pourrait être interprété dans le mauvais sens. Chacun comprend qu'il y a une ambiguïté dans ce style de question.