# Comment l'adverbe « si » a-t-il glissé sémantiquement pour signifier « au contraire » ?

Tags: étymologie, latin

> [[ Etymologie: ]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/si#.C3.89tymologie) ([Adverbe](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/si#fr-adv)) [4.]  Du latin [*sic*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sic#la) (« [ainsi](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ainsi) »).
>
> [[ Definitions : ]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/si#fr-adv) 1. Au contraire. 2. Tellement.
> 3. (Populaire) (À la fin d’une phrase négative) N’est-ce pas ?

1 and 4 m'apparaissent contradictoire et opposé. Imaginez un Latinophone  qui pose une question négative comme : Tu n'utilises pas Stackexchange ?

Si je réponds *sic*, le Latinophone comprendra que sa question négative est « ainsi ». = Sa question négative reflète la réalité. = Je n'utilise pas Stackexchange. Donc, *sic* = oui, et non pas 1 ci-dessus.

Comment: *Sic* n'est pas utilisé dans le langage parlé usuel. C'est une locution latine que l'on retrouve dans les témoignages pour signifier que "c'est ainsi qu'il a parlé" (et donc la faute, la tournure n'est pas celle de l'auteur). La logique de l'utilisation de *si* demande des cas d'espèces précis, et non des raisonnements sur des concepts.

Comment: Pourquoi est-ce qu'il comprendrait "je n'utilise pas Stack Exchange" ? Si on répond "non" ça veut dire qu'on ne l'utilise pas, donc c'est logique de réponse "oui" si on l'utilise, non ? Je vois "si" simplement comme un "oui", il s'y substitue dans certaines phrases, mais en anglais par exemple on se comporte de la même façon, le "si" étant simplement un "yes". Là où un français répondrait "si", un anglais répondrais "yes I do", donc il n'y a aucune raison de penser qu'en répondant "sic" un latinophone comprendrais ce qu'on exprimerait par "non".

Comment: Voir http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/848/differences-between-oui-and-si-in-the-affirmative et http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19389/si-ou-oui-pour-contredire-une-question-affirmative

Answer (score 1):

Ce n'est pas vraiment un glissement de sens opposé, c'est une conséquence du sens "positif", car le "si" contrarie une proposition négative, ce qui aboutit à du positif, et non de la négation, comme on pourrait le croire en lisant dans la définition "au contraire".

-> L'emploi de "si" pour dire "au contraire, c'est bien le cas", se fait après une phrase négative.

> - Tu ne vas pas au travail aujourd'hui ? Si, j'y vais!

"Il contredit un énoncé négatif". Le "si" est sans doute une simplification d'une formule qui comptait deux mots, comme l'ancien "si fait" (qui a vraiment un air de famille avec le *sic* latin), qui ne se dit plus, sauf dans les anciennes pièces de théâtres.
Il revient à dire "*Mais si*!", "*Oh si*!, "*Oh que si*!", etc... bien que ces formulations aient encore plus de force dans l'opposition qu'un simple "si" tout seul.

Le TILF dit qu'on l'utilise "En réponse à une question rhétorique de forme négative invitant à une réponse affirmative."
C'est-à-dire que si on répondait par l'affirmative (oui), à la question, on confirmerait la négation, ou en tout cas, il y aurait une certaine ambiguïté.

> - Tu ne vas pas au travail aujourd'hui? Oui

Oui quoi? Oui tu y vas, ou oui tu n'y vas pas?

> - Tu ne vas pas au travail aujourd'hui? Non.

Dans ce cas la phrase n'a pas d’ambiguïté, la personne n'ira pas.